# Can I deploy an Elastic Beanstalk application from a local ZIP file not a S3 object with Terraform?

Tags: node.js, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to deploy an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Node.js application based on a local ZIP file with Terraform?

All examples I have seen are S3 based.

Here is my code so far:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "nodejs" {
  name = "NodeJSPolicy"
  policy = file("policy.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "nodejs" {
  name = "iam_for_lambda"
  assume_role_policy = file("assumerole.json")
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "nodejs" {
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.nodejs.arn
  role = aws_iam_role.nodejs.name
}

data "archive_file" "package"{
  type = "zip"
  source_file = "../app"
  output_path = "../build/package.zip"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "nodejs" {
  name = "nodejs-app"
  description = "Noodle JP Application"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "nodejs" {
  name = "v0.01"
  application = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.nodejs.name
  //**??????? HOW CAN I HAVE THE SOURCE HERE?**
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "nodejs" {
  application = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.nodejs.name
  name = "noodle-jp"
  solution_stack_name = "Node.js 14 AL2 version 5.4.6"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to deploy an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Node.js application based on a local ZIP file with Terraform?

**No, this is not supported by Terraform currently.**

The [`aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_application_version) Terraform resource is the resource that is used to point to the application source bundle.

It only takes in `bucket` & `key` as the S3 bucket name and S3 object name parameters respectively for defining the source.

> `bucket` - (Required) S3 bucket that contains the Application Version source bundle.
>
> `key` - (Required) S3 object that is the Application Version source bundle.

It does not support defining a local path.